# Date Formatting returns null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

My code to convert `String` to `Date` is:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-09-22 14:10:19";
NSDateFormatter *datetFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datetFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [datetFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Here, `date` value is `null` when I set `24-Hour Time` OFF in my device. When I set ON, it returns the correct date. Which is the dateFormat I should use to avoid `null` in both time formats on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this,

```
+ (NSDate*)parseDate:(NSString*)inStrDate format:(NSString*)inFormat {
    NSDateFormatter* dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:inFormat];
    NSDate* dateOutput = [dtFormatter dateFromString:inStrDate];
    [dtFormatter release];
    return dateOutput;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

NSDateFormatter returns `nil` when the given date string doesn't match the expected date format.

According to the [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) spec, `HH` is used for 0-23  hours, while `hh` is used for 0-12 with AM and PM. As you've found out the hard way, you can't mix them up.

If you need to convert date format templates, you should consider using `[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:]` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate%3aoptions%3alocale%3a)) to have the framework convert between time format formatters as needed -- e.g.: to go from your default format to the user's localized format.

Comment: `dateFormatFromTemplate` is indeed useful to convert to or from a date string in the user's locale. But here, the string comes from a server and has a fixed format (which exactly matches the specified date format). The task here is to *ignore* the locale settings.

Comment: @MartinR How do you know that? It wasn't mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: Of course I might be misinterpreting it. But that the string exactly matches the date format can be seen in the question. Also the problems were reported for the case that the *device settings* are switched from 24hr to 12hr format (not when changing the date format or the input string). That the strings comes from a server was mentioned in a comment to a (now deleted) answer.

Answer (score 4):

For date conversions that are independent of the current device settings, 
you have to set a fixed locale:

```
NSLocale *posixLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[datetFormat setLocale: posixLocale];
```

(Compare [Technical Q&A QA1480 "NSDateFormatter and Internet Dates"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1480.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're not sure (or don't care) about the date format contained in the string, use NSDataDetector for parsing date.

```
//Role players.
NSString *dateString = @"Wed, 03 Jul 2013 02:16:02 -0700";
__block NSDate *detectedDate;

//Detect.
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingAllTypes error:nil];
[detector enumerateMatchesInString:dateString
                       options:kNilOptions
                         range:NSMakeRange(0, [dateString length])
                    usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{ detectedDate = result.date; }];
```

Answer (score 0):

12 hour and 24 hour both of work perfectly. i tested with sample project

```
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"hh:mm a" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
        NSString *startDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"%@",startDate);
```